# cannot access asp.net server side control from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

cannot access asp.net server side control from jquery

Label

```
<label id="lblClanName" runat="server">Something here</label>
```

Jquery

```
  $('#test').click(function () {
        var yle = ('#"<%= lblClanName.ClientID %>"').val;
        alert(yle);
    });
```

button:

```
<input type="button" id="test" value="TesTme" />
```

alert returns undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var yle = ('#"<%= lblClanName.ClientID %>"').val;
```

Should be:

```
 var yle = $('#<%= lblClanName.ClientID %>').val();
```

Comment: shouldn't be `$` be placed before `('#<%= lblClanName.ClientID %>').val();` or im missing something

Answer (score 1):

You should not have double quotes and also you are missing `$` and `()` in `val` method call in your code. Try this.

```
$('#test').click(function () {
    var yle = $('#<%= lblClanName.ClientID %>').val();
    //Note here
              ^                                     ^
              |                                     |
             $ was missing                      () as missing
    alert(yle);
});
```

**Update**

Since you are trying the get the text of a label element, use `text()` method instead of `val()`. Try this.

```
var yle = $('#<%= lblClanName.ClientID %>').text();
```

Comment: @Acid - Because label do not have `value` use `text()` instead it will work.

Comment: :) i already tried Text(), innercontent, innertext, innerhtml some shit here

Comment: When i used jquery in asp.net always was problem. Does it only my problem?

Comment: Use `text()` and not `Text()`. JavaScript is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You need parenthesis for your `val` function call:

```
//notice the `$` to make this a valid jQuery selection, 
//also the double quotes have been removed from the selector,
//and the parenthesis were added to the `val()` call
var yle = $('#<%= lblClanName.ClientID %>').val();
```

You were referencing the `val` function but not running it.

You would reference a function as you have if you were trying to just pass a reference to the function without running it, for example:

```
setTimeout(myFunc, 5000);
```

Will call the function named `myFunc` after five seconds.

Comment: Good catch, you should explain why you made the changes to the code that you did...

Answer (score 0):

Just add `()` to the `val` function and remove the `"`:

```
  $('#test').click(function () {
        var yle = $("#<%= lblClanName.ClientID %>").val();
        alert(yle);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line..

```
var yle = ('#"<%= lblClanName.ClientID %>"').val;
```

Shoud be..

```
var yle = $('#"<%= lblClanName.ClientID %>"').val();
```

The two things where missed in your line... `jQuery selector` function which is.. `'$'` and `.val` should be `.val()`

Hope this helps!